# Closing divs by clicking on child div

Tags: jquery

I have been breaking my head over this - why is the code below not working?

```
<div class="what">
<ul>

<li class="popup1">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="big">Popup 1
            <div class="more">more+
                <div class="popup">Contents of popup 1</p>
                    <div class="close">x</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

...

<li class="popup3">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="big">Popup 3
            <div class="more">more+
                <div class="popup">Contents of popup 3</p>
                    <div class="close">x</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

And below is the jquery code that works mostly fine, but it doesn't when I click on the x within the div with class "x".

```
$(".what .more").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".popup").hide();
});


$(".what").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".more").click(function() {
        $(".popup").hide();
        $(this).find(".popup").show();
        // return false;
    });

    $(this).find(".more .close").click(function() {
        // alert();
        $(".popup").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Dcnf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both functions are executing when you click the close button because it is contained within the parent container having the `.more` class. Because Javascript is event based the `hide()` in each element runs at more or less the same time, and the `show()` is most likely to execute last, resulting in the DIV remaining visible.

You can fix this by moving `.more` to a different element that is not the parent of `.popup`

The code can also be simplified - you don't need to use the `each()` function for example.

```
// Hide all .popup elements when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".popup").hide();
});

// Clicking any ".more .link" element will show that elements related content
$(".more.link").click(function() {
    // Hide all
    $(".popup").hide();
    // Go to this elements parent and then find .popup and show it
    $(this).parent().find(".popup").show();
});

// Clicking any .close will only execute this function and hide all .popup elements
$(".close").click(function() {
    $(".popup").hide();
});
```

HTML with the new `<span class="more link"/>` element

```
<li class="popup1">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="big">Popup 1
            <div class="more">
                <span class="more link">more+</span>
                <div class="popup">Contents of popup 1
                    <div class="close">x</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

See a working version in this http://jsfiddle.net/M2dZN/1/

Comment: This indeed a working version, but isn't there any other way to get it working with my html code? The popup is taking it's position from the "more" class, now this is impossible.

Comment: You can add another class to the "more" element and make the selector more specific. Updated the code in the answer/fiddle.

Comment: Awesome, very detailed answer - and working perfectly. Thanks a lot.